Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE. Bumping dependencies to 18.0.2
I'm having these production crashes caused by gms libraries version 17.0.0, it was suggested to bump all related dependencies to 18.0.2 which I did.

All the following libraries we're bumped to 18.0.2,

play-services-tagmanager
play-services-auth-api-phone
play-services-maps

except, play-services-ads-identifier which is only at 18.0.1 as its latest version.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4520)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900 (ActivityThread.java:259)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2219)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:233)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:344)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8249)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:589)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1071)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: <app id omitted>: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
  at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags (PendingIntent.java:375)
  at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser (PendingIntent.java:651)
  at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast (PendingIntent.java:638)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zzbv.zzfe (zzbv.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zzbv.cancel (zzbv.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zzbv.zzaw (zzbv.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zzan.zzag (zzan.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zzap.<init> (zzap.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zzap.zzc (zzap.java)
  at com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver.onReceive (CampaignTrackingReceiver.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4504)

I have no idea what other dependencies might be causing this except the old gms libraries version that I can think of.
My work-runtime-ktx is at 2.8.1 which is a higher version from the version probably causing the issue mentioned in this post
Will this issue still occur if I leave play-services-ads-identifier at 18.0.1?

Does this answer your question? How to resolve "Missing PendingIntent mutability flag" lint warning in android api 30+?

The exception was caused by the CampaignTrackingReceiver, and within the stacktrace, the zzbv.java file uses a 0 intent flag, and likely causing the exception,

And since the crash report indicated,

The crash may be related to play-services-analytics-impl
(com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl

Bumping play-services-tagmanager to 18.0.2 might possibly fix the issue.
